# UITableViewController crashes silently without error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am new to iPhone app development so please be patient with me.

I have an UITableViewController which fetches an array of private messages threads using an API call.

I'm fetching the threads in viewDidLoad() and it has successfully stored into my class property of PMThreads. However the app just crashes silently after that without loading each thread into tableView.

This is the code I have: https://gist.github.com/884683

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured it out. It wasn't anything to do with ownership or retaining data.
I did my xib file improperly.

In my case, I put a UITableViewController, instead of a UITableView in the xib file. So in case anyone who share a similar experience, check your data ownership, as well as your xib file.

Answer (score 1):

You should not release the data that you receive from the NSURLConnection request.
Try that!

/Kalle

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Run your app with **Build and Debug**. When the crash happens, open up the the debugger console (Cmd-Shift-R) and type bt. Copy the backtrace (everything after you typed 'bt') from the debugger console. Edit your message here and paste the backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

As posted you're sending the release message to data and you don't even own the object. its currently in an autorelease pool. with no owner (ie. nothing has retained).

Read up on: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html

your releases should be equal to your (retain/alloc/copy).

Comment: Please enlighten me: why is it necessary for data to retain in memory?

I've loaded the API result in my class property. Isn't that enough to retain its life span throughout the class?